# How to show all news in one page with detail view in typo3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.x

I followed [this](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/UsersManual/HowToStart/Index.html) tutorial to create news page in typo3. But i want to show all news in side bar and detail view in same page. When i try create plugin element with detail view on same page, it show error

```
Reason: No news entry found.
```

[image: Screenshot of page]

I have pointed to same page for

```
PageId for single news display
```

for `list view(Without overloadin detail view)`.

How to i do that and how to enable `next page` and `prev page` if news contents exceeds 10?

Comment: If there is no news entry selected, the detail view is no able to display a news and will return ``Reason: No news entry found.`` Is there a starting point set in the plugin of the detail view?

Comment: It was not, but i did now. Still not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use the news documentation for this case.
[List and detail on the same page using TypoScript](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/IntegrationWithTypoScript/Index.html#list-and-detail-on-the-same-page-using-typoscript).
Important part is the condition.

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
  page.10.marks.content < lib.news_detail
[else]
  page.10.marks.content < lib.news_list
[end]
```